Tracking environment of deployment of User Story in Azure DevOps
How to track environment of a User Story / Requirement deployment in Azure DevOps?
What's the recommended way to track which environment a User Story / PBI/ Requirement is deployed to? We have DEV TEST and PROD environments.
I added custom states in my process to map these environments to In Process but the issue with this is that the work item is not considered in Complete state until PROD deployment and oftentimes it needs to wait in lower environments until the customer approves PROD deployment. Because of this, the requirements and child tasks on the cards, progress percentage etc don't reflect it's completed.
When I had them as custom states I was able to display them as columns and it was nice to drag drop them through environments. A custom field to tags to track environment will not be as convenient.
Suggestions?
Thanks!
